# Upgrading Liferay 6.2 maven plugins into Liferay 7 module

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-7, liferay-dxp

There are many sites which provides articles for upgrading liferay 6.2 to dxp but only for ant project. How can we upgrade liferay 6.2 maven project to liferay dxp gradle project ?

Answer (score 0):

The strategy to upgrade your code is exactly the same. Liferay's Plugins SDK defaulted to Ant until 6.2, now you have the choice between liferay-workspace (gradle based), gradle and maven - just choose the build environment you'd like (sounds like you'd like to continue with maven) and add your code to an empty blueprint for the project of your choice.

There's an upgrade tool in Liferay IDE that might help you - even if it doesn't use the build tool of your choice or if eclipse isn't the IDE of your choice: The upgrade tool is a one-off tool to use during upgrade. No matter what the result is on: You can always check (for example) [Liferay's blade-sample project](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples) to find the proper build descriptors for Maven - and adapt them to your project.

Edit: After the clarification: Your main task is still the upgrade of the code. As of moving from Maven to gradle: Identify the dependencies and translate from pom.xml syntax to gradle's declaration - the contents are similar (e.g. group, name, version), only how you're writing them down is different. If you have made elaborate custom modifications to your pom.xml try to go without them first. You can start with a stock build.gradle (e.g. from blade-samples that most closely match your project) and then fix compile-time dependencies as you go.

I'm not aware of an automated process that does this translation for you (and most likely you'd bump up a few version numbers in the process anyway)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I forgot to mention that I want to migrate from maven build tool to gradle while upgrading from 6.2 to dxp. I have edited the question.

Comment: I am executing **gradle init** where my pom.xml is located. It is creating gradle files for me. I am also **adding dependencies** which are updated in the liferay 7 **in build.gradle file**. Lastly I remove the xml files and provide declarative annotation in each portlet. Do I need to perform any other extra steps for proper upgradation ?